# Reading information from a page without Web Locators , Selenium , Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

```
xpath_id = '/html/body'
conf_code = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, (xpath_id))
code_list = []
for c in range(len(conf_code)):
    code_list.append(conf_code[c].text)
```

> as seen above i chose the xpath locator, but i can't locate the text, that is because this particular webpage is completly blank as only as text in the «body»
> the html of the page is bellow:

> «html» , «head», «body» 'text that i want to read and save' «body», «/html»

> how to read this text and then store it in a variable

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough.
Anyway, in case there are multiple elements containing texts on that page you can use something like this:

```py
xpath_id = '/html/body/*'
conf_code = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, (xpath_id))
code_list = []
for c in conf_code:
    code_list.append(c.text)
```

Don't forget to add some delay to make the page completely loaded before you getting all these elements from there

Comment: hey, i resolved the issue using a simple print(driver.page_source) which gave me the full HTML content, where i then extracted the <body> part from it. Everything else just returned errors after errors. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

If you're really just grabbing a website that is so simple, you don't need selenium. Grab the website with requests and split the result on the body tags to get the text. Much simpler code and avoids the overhead of the selenium driver.

```
import requests

url = "http://your-url-here.com"
content = requests.get(url).text
the_string_youre_looking_for = content.split('<body>')[1].split('</body>')[0]
```

Is this what you're looking for? If not, maybe try and reword your question, because it's a bit hard to understand what you want your code to do and in what context.

Comment: hey, i resolved the issue using a simple print(driver.page_source) which gave me the full HTML content, where i then extracted the <body> part from it. Everything else just returned errors after errors. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

I got full HTML content, and due to its simplicity it was easy to extract to required content withing the `<body>` TAG